# Rda files causing Windows build errors

Tags: r

My package can be found [on GitHub](http://github.com/jmcurran/relSim).

I am having trouble with the Windows build. Specifically I get this error:

```
Error in load(zfile, envir = envir) : 
input has been corrupted, with LF replaced by CR
ERROR: installing package indices failed
* removing 'C:/Users/James/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/relSim'
```

From an ancient Brian Ripley post I have discovered that my .rda files are the likely source of the error, and in Windows, as I cannot load them.

However, I am unsure what I am supposed to do to fix this problem. The package compiles just fine on Linux and OS X.

Comment: Possibly @Hack-R but will that work in a package?

Comment: It does not pass `R CMD check` on macOS. Even after re-"documenting" it with roxygen2 it still does not pass `R CMD check` tests with "1 ERROR, 1 WARNING, 1 NOTE"

Comment: @hrbrmstr working on it. roxygen2 implementation was only partial so a lot of rework to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the files into memory and then re-saving them seems to have fixed this error. It would be nice to know what caused it in the first place.